# SQL Query Finding Specific record by Date

Tags: sql, date, oracle10g

Working from an oracle 10g environment.

Suppose you were given: *NOTE (Duration is in Weeks)

```
CLASSNAME                 INSTURCTOR        DAYS     STARTDATE   *DURATION TIMESTART TIMEEND
------------------------- ----------------------- ------------- ---------  -------- --------
Power Dance               Robert Backman    MWF      03-MAR-11          2 0930       1100
Power Dance               Lynn Parker       MWF      03-MAY-11          2 0930       1100
Power Dance               Lynn Parker       MTTh     18-MAY-11          2 1230       0100
Club Stretch              Kevin Lopez      MT       24-OCT-11          3 1930          2015
Club Stretch              Kevin Lopez       F        17-JUN-11          3 1130       1300
Hatha Yoga                Susan Wanzer      MW       25-MAY-11          3 1900       2000
```

A user wants to be able to query the Classname, Instructor, Timestart, and TimeEnd for a class given a specific date.

I understand how to find the EndDate using (Duration * 7) + StartDate. The trouble I am having is finding out which classes are running on a day of the week. As in say the user enters in 24-JUN-11, the only class that should show up should be Club Stretch.

Answer (score 0):

It might be just a matter of rephrasing your question: you want to know which classes are starting at of before the specified date and are ending at or after this specified date.
You already have the starting date and you know how to calculate the ending date.

This will be your solution:

```
SELECT [columns] 
FROM [table] 
WHERE @specifiedDate BETWEEN [startDate] AND [calculatedEndDate]
    AND [days] LIKE @specifiedWeekday
```

`@specifiedWeekday` should, when looking for a Monday, have a value like this (in MS SQL): `'%M%'`

NOTE: Just now read your working in Oracle. This is a SQL Server answer. I hope the idea behind it will help you along.

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit unclear, the intent is so that the user enters in a date, say May-31-2011 which is a Tuesday and the results should be only the classes that meet on Tuesdays that are in session during that period. The way I have it working now is that if the user enters in May-31-2011 I can return the classes that are  active during that time period, but not the exact classes meeting that day.

Comment: Do you have an influence on how the data is stored in this table? Can you store the days with a separator in between? Like M;T;Th;F;? The way the days are currently stored, it's hardly impossible to ignore Thursdays when you are looking for Tuesdays.

Comment: Yeah I realized that problem, I am considering going back to the original tables and changing them to more appropriate entries since like you said, it is very difficult to differentiate Tuesdays and Thursdays. 
If they were separated or Thursday was an R instead, would it be possible to query as I described?

Comment: If you are able to determine the weekday in your application or in Oracle, you could extend the statement with a LIKE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you need to first determine the day of the week store that as a variable that you would feed to the second to the second query. Query sample for first part below:

```
select to_char(to_date('31-May-2011','dd-Mon-yyyy'),'DAY') from dual
SQL> /

TO_CHAR(T
---------
TUESDAY
```

or

```
select to_char(to_date('31-May-2011','dd-Mon-yyyy'),'DY') from dual
TO_
---
TUE
```

then you could feed that into your other query with your now known day of the week.  If you need to decode it to the formats you mention then the following code will convert the day of the week to the abbreviations you are showing:

```
select decode(to_char(to_date('26-May-2011','dd-Mon-yyyy'),'DY'), 'MON','M',
                                                                  'TUE','T',
                                                                  'WED','W',
                                                                  'THU','Th',
                                                                  'FRI','F',
                                                                  'SAT','Sa','Su') 
from dual
```

will return the Th you are using :)